# Hide text selection markers in Android stock browser

Tags: android, hide, markers, textselection

I'm in a position where I really need to hide the text selection "markers" when editing an input field in the **Android stock browser**. They are in the way for other important information. It's a JSP-page. Is this technically possible?

Just to avoid any misunderstandings I'm adding and image to show what I mean:

[image: Text selection image]

Comment: In the android stock browser? Are you making a web app.. please clarify?

Comment: Are you trying to say you do not want the functionality of clipboard ?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, a bit stressed. 
It's Android Stock browser, it's a JSP-page. So javascript or CSS would be the solution. I know the broswer has a set of it's own specific classes for certain features. But I haven't found anything for this cause.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK There is not such way to disable the selection of the Text for EditText in android.

Comment: If this is an `EditText` in a person's own app, it can be achieved by overriding the `onSelectionChanged`

Comment: Yeah, I figured. But this is unfortunately the stock broswer.